# What is a summary of the token standard debate?

Tags: tokens, protocol, erc-20

I've been seeing some talks about replacing ERC20 with a better standard. I think I'm slightly out of the loop, though.

1. What is, in summary, the limitations and/or issues with ERC20?
2. How will the proposed standard improve and solve those limitations and/or issues?
3. Is it generic enough? I.e., do we know that the new standard doesn't also have limitations and/or issues that will cause it to be replaced in a future?

Comment: Do you have a link to some of the discussions you've seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a partial answer to your first question.
There is a thread in Github started by maraoz stating:

*The main problems with ERC20 standard token are:
Lack of reference implementation and tests
Higher complexity due to approve functionality, which not all projects need.
Returns boolean values to signal failure instead of throwing.
Function totalSupply() could just be implemented as a state variable in most cases.*  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/179

If you go to the thread, you will see comments and responses to his statement.